# use of infinito

Tags: word-meaning, meaning, sentences

I understand that this sentence

> Sei libero però non profittartene.

means “You are free but you don't take benefit from this (your freedom).”

It seems to me profittartene is an infinito. Is the sentence correct and why do we use an infinito in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "... but don't take benefit from this". It's a negative imperative, which in the singular has the same form as the infinitive.

Comment: I'd say more something like “...but don't take advantage of this” or “...don't abuse this”.